# Align all content with the bottom of the page?

Tags: css

I'm trying to align a html-page with the bottom of the browser-window. This is my apporach:

```
<body>
  <div class="outer-wrapper">
  </div>
</body>

.outer-wrapper{
    min-height: 950px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that when the screen is smaller than 950px high, the top of the outer-wrapper disapears above the screen and no scroll is added. Both the body and the outer-wrapper has a background-image.

Here is a sample, as you can see, the top of the red box is above the body.
http://jsfiddle.net/C5Nce/1/

Comment: Is it necessary for your wrapper to be a minimum height of 950px?

Comment: Yes, it has graphics in it(and also content). Although I could set height 950px

Comment: So you want something that is fixed to the bottom of the page but to also get scroll bars if the body is smaller than the absolutely positioned element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following demo should work, if I understand what you want correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/C5Nce/10/show/

I just used a media query to detect when the page is less than 550px and set the element to be pinned to the top instead:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 550px) {
       .outer_wrapper {
           top: 0;
       }
}
```

I've coloured it green so you can tell when the query fires.

Answer (score 0):

I would just give your `outer-wrapper` a height of 100% (along with html, body):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.outer-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-position:bottom; //Edit
}
```

Then the `outer-wrapper` will always keep the body's height. There’s no need for the 950px height min because in the case that the viewport is too small you wanted for this to scroll and in the other case the viewport is bigger than 950px - well, it's bigger than 950px - that's a good thing.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the .outer-wrapper has a background. When I scroll, the background doesn't show below the fold.

Comment: The `outer-wrapper` background will still scroll with the div content. If you want to change this you can do with the [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-attachment) property.

Comment: I'm trying to align the background with the bottom of the document.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren You can use `background-position`? See my update

Comment: Yes I can, however, the problem is that if I don't position the .outer-wrapper with bottom: 0, the outer wrapper ends at the same place as the fold does.

Answer (score 0):

```
.outer {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#aaaaaa;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.content {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    background-color:#444444;
    margin:5%;
}
.inner {
    position:absolute;
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom:10%;
}
```

---

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/L8H9J/

1) Remove the margin-bottom style from the inner class

2) All the content you add inside the inner class will be aligned with the bottom

3) Because of the flow of the document in HTML, you cannot explicitly align them with the 
bottom

4) You can use this trick to do so, but again all elements inside the inner class will be 
with flow of `position:static`

5) There comes the use of JavaScript to determine suitable margins for each element inside 
the inner class

**Tip:** `Use percentages; although you want the wrapper to be of height ~950px, but if you can use percentages for the dimensions, you would really love watching your web applications scale with the browsers:`

[image: image-1]
[image: image-2]

Answer (score -1):

Edit section from your code [here](http://jsbin.com/iqerup/2/edit)

```
.outer_wrapper 
{
    background-color:red;
    /*min-height: 550px;*/
    margin-left: -75px; 
    top:auto;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
}
```

and you are specifying your **red box is above the body**, if you put it inside body it supposed to be placed like it as you also have specify `min-height` of container.

Comment: If I add top:0, the .outer-wrapper aligns with the top of the page rather tahn the bottom...

Comment: i have specified zero beacuse i thought you want a container that could hold its size upon resizing of page as it worked for me.

Comment: can you post a screen shot of it.

Comment: I added a JS-fiddle to the question, PS. It was not me who downvoted your suggestion.